# Send the response to user from other file instead of views.py form DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on DRF in which I have created multiple pythons and importing that file into views.py but when I am trying to send the response to the user from another file it is not working I understand the behind the reason but is there any way to send the response to the user from other than view.py.

view.py Structure

```
#restframework view and all
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import other as o
call FileView(APIView):
   #parseclass 
   def post(self,request):
       o.func(d)
```

Other.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import status
from django.conf import setting

def func(d):
    return Response({"A":"OK"})
```

but Response is not coming to the user end.

is there any way to send a response from other.py to the user instead of getting value and then send the response from the view.py?

I am also implementing multithreading in my DRF.

Answer (score 0):

Just add return and it should work:

```
class FileView(APIView):
    #parseclass 
    def post(self,request):
        return o.func(d)
```

If you want to skip this step and call view in others.py directly. Just make that an APIView and register it in urls.py. It should work

Comment: Eklof, can you please illustrate this once.